# Which is more secure: Certificate or Secret inside our Azure Active Directory App, and why?

Tags: certificates, azure, secrets-management

Inside our Azure Active Directory, we have 2 options to secure our calls to the Active Directory App:

1. Secret
2. Certificate

[image]

Which option is more secure and why? Inside our applications which will be calling this App, it either needs to send the client secret or the certificate thumbprint.

Microsoft says in the image above:

> For a higher level of assurance, we recommend using a certificate
> (instead of a client secret) as a credential.

but I am not sure why a certificate is more secure.

Second question, if we assume that the certificate is more secure, then is a self-signed certificate more secure than using a secret?

Comment: And the question boils down to "passwords vs certificates" and that's a google search term with a ton of rich results and explanations.

Comment: @schroeder i am asking about secret vs certificate and not username/password versus certificate

Comment: Shared secret is always a shared secret regardless the name. You are really comparing shared secrets with public key authentication. The answer to that is clear.

Comment: @EsaJokinen i am nto sure why i keep getting links instead of a clear answer. thanks anyway for the link will check it

Comment: @EsaJokinen also i am asking about the differences between Secrets and  certificate and not user/name vs certificate + i am asking specifically about azure active directory app

Comment: Why would the answer be different for different applications? The pros and cons are exactly the same. Shared secret is a shared secret: it is known by both parties and transferred during the authentication.

Comment: @EsaJokinen the link talks abut username/password i am asking about secrets + what about my second question `Second question, if we assume that the certificate is more secure, then is a self-signed certificate more secure than using a secret?

`

Comment: @johnGu I don't think you are understanding. It's exactly the same thing ...

Comment: The second question is asked separately here: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/268216/70406

Comment: @EsaJokinen i think this forum is to ask a question you have and get answers ... yes i agree with you `I don't think you are understanding` otherwise i would not ask this question ??

Comment: @EsaJokinen this post https://security.stackexchange.com/q/268216/70406 is different than my second question here, they are regarding self-signed certificates but have different questions

Comment: @EsaJokinen so why you close this question ? it is not a duplicate to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/certificate-based-authentication-vs-username-and-password-authentication ~~~

Comment: Ok, now you are choosing to not understand.

Comment: @schroeder and you are choosing to take irrelevant actions

Comment: I'll repeat, yet again: secrets and passwords are the same thing. As for the 2nd part of your question, please limit posts to one question at a time. And you have repeated that part of the question in a completely different post...

Comment: @schroeder one question i am comparing self-signed certificate with secrets, the other question is regarding using self-signed certificate in production environments... if they were same question i would not ask 2 different questions.. thanks for your understanding